# Check if a class or id exist in html response from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know we can use `hasClass()` but in my case my ajax is returning html.

I can append then check the class exist or not but there'll be a flick. Is it possible to check what's inside the html before render it somewhere?

```js
$.ajax({
  url:'some_url',
  success: function(html) {
    // I can do this:
    $('body').append(html);
    if ($('my_selector').length > 0) {
      // but I don't want to do this because I don't want that the html will show to the user
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You can simply check the returning HTML by placing that check in the success function of ajax and use async parameter is ajax call so that it will run after ajax call completes.

Comment: @Moax6629 I got my html but how to check whether the html contain specified  class or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further @Mohammad Adil answer:

```js
var html = '<div class="test">This is the response from the ajax call.</div>';

function simulateAjax(selector) {
  var exist = $('<div />').html(html).find(selector).length > 0;
  $('#result').append('The element "' + selector + '" ' + (exist ? '' : 'not ') + 'exist<br />');
}

simulateAjax('.test');
simulateAjax('.test1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The difference between the answers, and I think that the reason it didn't work for you, that for example: If your response is `<div class="test"></div>`, the @Mohammad's script will return `false` because there is no element with the class `.test` **in** the main element in the response.

So, you should wrap the response with element, **then** you can use `.find()` to check.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Possible

```
var yourReturnedHtml = getHtml();
return $(yourReturnedHtml).find('.someClass').length > 0;
```

Comment: How does this happen ?

Comment: ur second line is half way done, can I use hasClass to check whether it exist or not?

Comment: you can check if `$(yourReturnedHtml).find('.someClass').length` is `> 0` or not. (if you want to check if some class exist within your html)

Answer (score 0):

Sure working method, used many time into my projects, This will help you find any elements, elements with some class or id.

You can append your ajax response to some hidden html element  e.g div

e.g.

```
<div id="responseDiv" style="display: none"></div>

//Now write a function to save ajax response to div
//from this div, you can find out whether class or any element is there

$.ajax({
   url: 'some url',
   success: function(data){

      //save response to div
      $('#responseDiv').html(data);

      //now to check whether some class exists in the div
      if($('#responseDiv .class-to-find').length > 0){
           //since class is found into ajax response, write your code here

      }
   }
});
```

Comment: You can alway call setTimeout function with code in between single or double quotes.

e.g. setTimeout('function(){ //Your ajax code here }', 0);

This will work

Answer (score 0):

i got your point now. Use the same approach of hasClass() in success function of ajax and using async parameter. To remove the flick, place your ajax code is seTimeOut with time 0 like

```
setTimeout(function(){ //Your ajax code here }, 0);
```